# Dynamically assign a variable value to a html attribute

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a button that upon clicking would open a certain modal that is decided by the controller in a variable instead of just having multiple buttons that have the same attributes but with different data-targets

So this is one of the buttons that I was using earlier

```
      <button mat-menu-item class="menu-item" *ngIf="isReady"
              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ready-modal">
        <span>View Ready</span>
      </button>
```

and here's what I came up with

```
      <button mat-menu-item class="menu-item" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="{{action.dataModalTarget}}" (click)="this[action.clickFunction](event)">
          <span>{{action.translationKey | translate}}</span>
      </button>
```

however, this throws the following exception,

```
Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("      <button mat-menu-item class="menu-item" data-toggle="modal"
```

is this even doable or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via attribute binding, just like you bind properties and events, the syntax for attribute binding is:

```
[attr.<attribute_name>]="value"
[attr.data-target]="action.dataModalTarget"
```

Reference: [Angular doumentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-types-and-targets)

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me what attr refer to, or guide me to somewhere I can read a bit more about this ?